# Calculating distance from points to different class in raster using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, distance, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am looking for some advice on how to calculate the distance from a point to a different class of a raster.

Specifically, I have observations (points) of animal use overlaid on land cover data.

For each point I want to calculate the distance to the nearest cell of a different cover type.

For instance, if a point is located in a grassland patch, what is the distance to the nearest cell that is not grass.

I am using ArcGIS 10 and have a Spatial Analyst license.

I think raster calculator might be the best approach for this but could anyone provide an equation that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe there's a single command to do this, but we can still accomplish it expediently.  The idea is that *the distance to the nearest different cell equals the distance to the nearest location whose immediate neighborhood contains more than one cell type.*

Well, this is not quite true, but it's close: you might want to add approximately one cell width to such a distance.  If you can live with such an approximation, here's the workflow:

1. Compute a [focal variety](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000qs000000.htm) grid using as small a neighborhood as possible, which would be a 2 by 2 square neighborhood.
2. [Nullify](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Set_Null/009z00000007000000/) all locations with a focal variety of 1 or less: these are the "inside" cells.
3. Compute the [Euclidean distance](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Euclidean_Distance/009z0000001p000000/) grid to all remaining cells: these are the distances to locations along boundaries.
4. (Optional) [Add](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Plus/009z00000096000000/) the cellsize to the distance grid.
5. [Extract the values](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Extract_Values_to_Points/009z0000002t000000/) at any points you choose.

To illustrate, here is a small piece of a grid colored by cell type.  The black areas are the cells with focal varieties of 2 or greater (computed at step 2):

[image: Cell classes]

A hillshaded Euclidean distance grid looks like this:

[image: Distance grid]

It reaches peaks (maximum values) within the centers of each patch of the original raster and decays to zero along the patch boundaries, still shown with black.